# How to count values in multiple rows and line them in 1 row in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

## Ideal

```
____A___B___C    Result

1___@___@___?    @ 4

2___!___!___@    ! 3

3___?___!___@    ? 2
```

I tried =query(G6:FI1005, "select A,B,C count(A:C)") or filter(A1:C3) , but they failed and show warning.

I hope there is an answer, also I'd like to know the following more difficult situation as well.

```
____A___B___C___D___E___F     Result 

1___NO__''__OK__''__OK__''    @  at  2

2___@___at__@___at__!___sin   !  sin 1

3___?___que_@___at__?___que   ?  que 1
```

1: select rows where the column1 is "OK"

2: showing the next cell's value.

3: count as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, try this formula:

`=QUERY(ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",{A:A;B:B;C:C}),","))&{"",""}),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc")`

For question 2 try:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A2:F,A1:F1="OK")&" "&FILTER(B2:G,A1:F1="OK")&"|"),"|"))&{"",""},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>' ' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc"))`

I set up this example sheet to show them working:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfFETs_5Tia5UILNGTBD9oUneZfSJZ8VeVgwnNetsu8/edit?usp=sharing